# Round G - Kick Start 2020 Problem Kick_Start Wrong Answer

Tags: python, python-3.x

Problem:

> Ksenia is very fond of reading so she kicks off each day by reading a
> fragment from her favourite book before starting with the rest of her
> morning routine. A fragment is simply a substring of the text. Ksenia
> is somewhat superstitious and believes that her day will be lucky if
> the fragment she reads starts with the string KICK, then goes on with
> 0 or more characters, and eventually ends with the string START, even
> if the overall fragment makes little sense.
>
> Given the text of the book, count the number of different lucky
> fragments that Ksenia can read before the book gets old and she needs
> to buy another one. Two fragments are considered to be different if
> they start or end at different positions in the text, even if the
> fragments read the same. Also note that different lucky fragments may
> overlap.

Input:

> The first line of the input gives the number of test cases T. T lines
> follow, each containing a single string S consisting of upper case
> English letters only.

Output:

> For each test case, output one line containing Case #x: y, where x is
> the test case number (starting from 1) and y is the number of
> different lucky fragments in the text of this test case.

Limits:

> Memory limit: 1 GB. 1 ≤ T ≤ 100. S consists of upper-case English
> letters only.

Test Set 1:

Time limit: 20 seconds.
1 ≤ |S| ≤ 1000.

Test Set 2:

Time limit: 40 seconds.
1 ≤ |S| ≤ 105.

Sample:

```
Input
3
AKICKSTARTPROBLEMNAMEDKICKSTART
STARTUNLUCKYKICK
KICKXKICKXSTARTXKICKXSTART

Output
Case #1: 3
Case #2: 0
Case #3: 5
```

I tried solving it using Python. The logic I tried using is to find indices for substring `'KICK'` and substring `'START'` and find number of `START` appearing after every `'KICK'`.

I'm getting wrong answer I don't understand what edge cases I'm missing.

Here is the code:

```
import re

t = int(input())

for i in range(t):
    text = input()
    matches = 0
    temp1 = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('KICK',text)]
    temp2 = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('START',text)]
    if len(temp1) == 0 or len(temp2) == 0:
        matches = 0
    else:
        for ele in temp1:
            for x in temp2:
                if(x > ele):
                    matches = matches + 1
    print("Case "+"#"+str(i+1)+": "+str(matches))
```

Comment: Reading the assignment must count as cruel and unusual punshment.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the cases the code misses.

re.finditer() can only count **non-overlapping** matches and hence strings like 'KICKICK' would result in counting KICK only for 1 time rather than 2.

```
re.finditer(pattern, string, flags=0)
Return an iterator yielding MatchObject instances over all non-overlapping matches for the RE pattern in string.The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. Empty matches are included in the result.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code:

```
t = int(input())
for x in range(t):
    s = input()
    ans = 0
    k = 0
    for i in range(len(s)-4):
        if s[i:i+4] == "KICK":
            k += 1
            
        if s[i:i+5] == "START" and k != 0:
            ans += k
    print("Case #{}: {}".format(x+1, ans))
```

You are not considering all the possibilities. The code just shows how many time the KICK and START occurs

Comment: What I'm trying to do is store starting indices of all occurrences of  KICK in list temp1 and START in temp2 and then taking each index from KICK and find all occurrences of START after it and increasing the count. Your solution is correct could you help to find out what is wrong with my approach.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this works.

```
T=int(input())
for x in range(1, T + 1):   
P=input()
    c=0
    for i in range(0,len(P)-4+1):
        if (P[i:i+4]=="KICK"):
            for j in range(i+4,len(P)-5+1):
                if (P[j:j+5]=="START"):
                    c=c+1
    print("Case #{}: {}".format(x, c), flush = True)
```